# How to resolve warning: 'NSArray' may not respond to '-objectForKey:'

Tags: iphone, warnings

warning: 'NSArray' may not respond to '-objectForKey:'

```
PicsCount = [[[results objectForKey:@"wallper"] objectForKey:@"total"] intValue];
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

NSArray has no method 'objectForKey'. You may want an NSDictionary.

Answer (score 7):

`NSArray` does not have an `objectForKey` method. `NSDictionary` does.

Comment: someone copy/pasted their comment... made me laugh at this hour